# Need of refresh of iAd Banner?

Tags: objective-c, iad, ads, adbannerview

in my IOS game, I have two ViewControllers: One MenuViewController and the other one is the ViewController, on which I have a SKView for the game itself and a UIImageView, which I use as a restartView to restart the game after "gameover" and is only displayed then.

So I want to use iAd only if my "restartView" is displayed. While the game is running, theres no ad displayed, but it's initialized, yet (because the viewController is already loaded). If theres a "gameover" I set the alpha of the adBannerView to 1 and the alpha of my restartView to 1.

**The question is now:** Will I get revenue from this adBannerView, because it's the same one all the time, but only displayed if theres a "game over" and faded out if the user restarts the game (But it's in the background though).

Should I use interstitial ads or is there a possibility to reload an adBannerView or does it work this way without problems ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: GO through this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html ...... It'll help you...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So, in the documentation theres the information, that new ads will be load automatically in the background. Does that mean, I have nothing to do and it's ok, that I only set the alpha to 0 and to 1 if it should be displayed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Amir yes, and also this is available for iOS 4 and onwards.